# Print Tree With Recursive Function

Tags: c, recursion

My goal is: when I input "e c d g a f b", then the output is

```
e

(\t) c                <- first left node

(\t)(\t) a            <- second left node

(\t)(\t)(\t) b        <- third right node

(\t)(\t) d            <- second right node

(\t) g                <- first right node

(\t)(\t) f            <- second left node
```

But I can't get it to work as intended.

This is an example from "The C programing Language" by Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie.

I change my functions, how can i see \t in output window.

My attempt:

```
void prt(AW *p)
{
int j;
int temp;

if(p != NULL)
{   
          temp = judge;

    while(1)
    {   temp = temp / 2;
        count++;
        if(temp == 0)
            break;
    }

    for(j=1; j<count; j++)
        putchar('\t');
    printf("%-16s\n",p->word);

    count=0;

    if(p->left != NULL)judge++;
    prt(p->left);       

    if(p->right != NULL)judge++;
    prt(p->right);      }
```

}

Comment: @Vyktor I'm thinking its something along the lines of "fix the code plz?"

Comment: I have to say though, the local function prototype of `void prttree(AW *l,AW*r);` inside `prt(AW *p)` coupled with the global `count` adds a particularly challenging *zest* to debugging this. Especially since we have no idea what `count` starts at, or even *is*. vtc.

Answer (score 3):

suppose you have struct like this below.

```
typedef struct
{
int data;
struct node * left;
struct node *right;
} node; 



 void printtreenode(node *root)
    {
    if(root == NULL)
      return;
    printtreenode(root -> left);
    printf("%d\n",root -> data);
    printtreenode(root ->right);
    }
```

No need to pass 2 arguments to `printtreenode` and see it's recursive also.
This should work and you can modify it according to your formatted output.

Comment: You'll probably need a second parameter to tell the node depth to fix the proper indentation.

Comment: Yeah I have written that.. function can be modified but , mainly answered for recursive call OP mentioned

Comment: then how can output \t ( tab ). I need to put '\t'. i tried to put tab as counting but i fail.

Comment: @SeoGangWon: printf or putchar perhaps?